# Solution to System of linear inequalities 3x3

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a 3x3 system of linear inequalities
$A =\left(
\begin{matrix}
a_1-1 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & a_2-1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & α_3 -1
\end{matrix}\right)
$
where $a_1,a_2,a_3>1$

I want to solve the system $A\vec{x}<\vec{0}$ where $A$ is the above matrix and $x$ is a vector $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ . I am looking for

1. a formula that I could replace the $a_1,a_2,a_3$ and find the solution. Or a simple way to find heuristically an answer.
2. if it is easy to find solutions of the inequality such that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are integers where $x=[x_1,x_2,x_3]$

Comment: what does $Ax<0$ mean?

Comment: @Surb I did some edits. I mean $Ax<\vec{0}$

Comment: The question is still very unclear. Is $x$ given or not? Also, please explain what you have tried and where you are stuck

Comment: what do you know anbout analytic geometry (planes, lines etc. in 3d)?

Comment: @Surb It is like a linear system but with inequalities. The $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are some parameters and I want to find a solution to this system of inequalities given these parameters. I don't know what could I use ... does the simplex method of linear programming works for this ? or something else

Comment: @GCab Not much, but if you elaborate more ..tell me your thoughts and I will reply if I don't understand

Comment: I provided a hint for how to start: can you take on ?

Answer (score 0):

*just a starting hint*

Linear disequalities are much more involved than equalities., and diophantine inequalities more than continuous inequalities.

That premised we have better first of all to get rid of most of
all the minus signs
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 {\bf Ax} < {\bf 0}\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left( { - {\bf A}} \right){\bf x} = {\bf Mx} > {\bf 0} \\ 
 {\bf M} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {1 - a_1 } & 1 & 1  \\
   1 & {1 - a_2 } & 1  \\
   1 & 1 & {1 - a_3 }  \\
\end{array}} \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

Then
$$
ax + by + cz = 0
$$
is the equation of a plane, passing through the origin, whose unitary normal vector is
$$
{\bf n} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {a^2  + b^2  + c^2 } }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   a  \\   b  \\   c  \\\end{array}} \right)
$$
and
$$
ax + by + cz = d\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad
 \frac{{ax + by + cz}}{{\sqrt {a^2  + b^2  + c^2 } }}
 = \frac{d}{{\sqrt {a^2  + b^2  + c^2 } }}
$$
is a plane, parallel to the above, at signed distance $ \frac{d}{ \sqrt {a^2  + b^2  + c^2 }   }$
measured along $\bf n$.
Therefore
$$
ax + by + cz = d > 0
$$
at varying of $d$ span the semispace on the positive side of the plane through the origin above.

Finally,
$$
{\bf Mx} > {\bf 0}
$$
represents the intersection of the three semispaces given by each row inequality.